# Passing State as Prop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components

I want to a button show in some child components and don't show in other components. I used useState in parent component but couldn't pass it to child components. How can I do that?

```
  const [showRepo, setShowRepo] = useState(false);
const handleShowRepo = () => {
setShowRepo = !showRepo;
```

};

Where I use it;

```
<button className={!showRepo ? `${styles.viewRepo} ${styles.hideRepo}` : `${styles.viewRepo}`}>
          <a target="_blank" href={`${props.link}`}>
            {props.buttonText}
          </a>
        </button>
```

Comment: why not `setShowRepo(!showRepo)`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example as to how to pass a parent component state for a child component to use:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function Parent() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("Dolan The Duck");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dolan Family</h1>
      <Child name={name} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child(props) {
  return <h2>I am Luffy! {props.name}'s son!</h2>;
}
```

Let's break down this example:

1. The **Parent** component has a **name** state, when it renders the **Child** component it passes the state variable as a prop named **name**.
2. The **Child** component uses the prop **name** to render a cool heading, it does **props.name**.

Learn more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)